# Team Build Nuget restore failure with .NET Core 2.0 + .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, tfsbuild, nuget-package-restore

I have a VS2017 solution that contains a .NET Core 2.0 console project that references a .NET Standard 2.0 class library, as well as a number of other NuGet packages.  The solution builds fine on my development machine.

When I try to run NuGet restore on the TFS build server with NuGet 4.0.0 or 4.1.0, I get the following error:

```
    Package (mypackagename) 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package (mypackagename) 1.0.0 supports:
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
```

This error message is similar to that described in [Nuget restore fails for ASP.NET Core 2.0 project on build server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45723797/13087) so I tried the solution suggested there, which is to use NuGet 4.3.0 or later.   I've tried all released versions from 4.3.0 to 4.6.2, and this time I get the following error from NuGet restore:

```
2018-04-17T15:45:15.2611952Z Value cannot be null.
2018-04-17T15:45:15.2611952Z Parameter name: key
2018-04-17T15:45:15.2611952Z System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
2018-04-17T15:45:15.2611952Z Parameter name: key
2018-04-17T15:45:15.2611952Z    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
2018-04-17T15:45:15.2611952Z    at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommandProvidersCache.GetOrCreate(String globalPackagesPath, IReadOnlyList`1 fallbackPackagesPaths, IReadOnlyList`1 sources, SourceCacheContext cacheContext, ILogger log)
2018-04-17T15:45:15.2611952Z    at NuGet.Commands.DependencyGraphSpecRequestProvider.Create(String projectNameToRestore, ExternalProjectReference project, HashSet`1 projectReferenceClosure, RestoreArgs restoreArgs, DependencyGraphSpec projectDgSpec)
2018-04-17T15:45:15.2611952Z    at NuGet.Commands.DependencyGraphSpecRequestProvider.GetRequestsFromItems(RestoreArgs restoreContext, DependencyGraphSpec dgFile)
2018-04-17T15:45:15.2611952Z    at NuGet.Commands.DependencyGraphSpecRequestProvider.CreateRequests(RestoreArgs restoreContext)
2018-04-17T15:45:15.2611952Z    at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<CreatePreLoadedRequests>d__11.MoveNext()
2018-04-17T15:45:15.2611952Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Any suggestions as to how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by setting "Clean = True" in the "Get Sources" task of my Team Build.

After doing this, I could use a recent version of NuGet (4.6.2), which no longer throws the ArgumentNullException above.

I suspect a bug in NuGet, where it gets confused by files left around from a previous build.